# How can I prompt for a destination folder in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a hard time making a batch file that will copy a file and let the user input the destination of where the copied file will be saved.

It should look like this:

```
file to be copied:
target drive:
```

Comment: The topic should describe your problem, please don't make topics like "I need help" - please read: [How do i ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Collect them as environment variables, like this:

```
set /p FileToCopy=File to copy?
set /p DestinationDrive=Target drive?
```

Then, access them as environment variables in your batch file:

```
%FileToCopy%
%DestinationDrive%
```