# How to automate copying files from external memory?

Tags: windows, command-line, sd-card, cmd.exe

I'm looking for an efficient way to copy pictures from SD card to HDD. I'm using adobe suite for editing, and I don't want to "clutter" my PC with otherwise useless software (like Picassa). It would be much nicer to have a .bat file stored on the SD card, that I could execute on any PC. This is what I have so far:

```
FOR %%f IN (*.jpg *.raw) DO XCOPY G:\DCIM\100MSDCF\"%%f" C:\images /m /y /d[:08-17-2014]
```

1. How to make "xcopy" command copy from current batch file destination, instead of pre-defined destination? (in this case, G drive)
2. Is it possible to use input from command line for /d[:date] parameter? (so that the user inputs the date in cmd line, instead of manually changing the .bat file)

For syntax of xcopy see:
http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true

All feedback is welcome, as I'm a new user here:) Hello world!

Comment: There are tons of tools that do file copying that are both and free.  Which of these tools have you decided does not meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

1. `.` references the current folder, as does `%CD%`.  `%~dp` returns the path where the batch file lives. Pick yer poison.
2. `set /p myVariable=Date?` will prompt the user for input ("Date? ") and place it in a variable (named "myVariable") for use.

More info:

- [Command line .cmd/.bat script, how to get directory of running script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130112/command-line-cmd-bat-script-how-to-get-directory-of-running-script)
- [Get current folder name by a DOS command?](https://superuser.com/questions/160702/get-current-folder-name-by-a-dos-command)
- [How can I prompt for a destination folder in a batch file?](https://superuser.com/questions/630905/how-can-i-prompt-for-a-destination-folder-in-a-batch-file)